# How do I prevent tmux from wrapping around when searching?

Tags: tmux

When I am in edit mode in a tmux pane and I do a search, once it reaches the end, it goes back to the beginning. Is there any setting to prevent this?

Comment: do you use `/` or `n` to search next result ?

Comment: After the first search with `/`, I use `n` to get the next results. I tried repeating the search with a combination of `/` and _Enter_, but the behaviour doesn't change, once it gets to the end, it comes back to the beginning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`tmux` now has a window option `wrap-search`:

> `wrap-search [on | off]`
>
> If this option is set, searches will wrap around the end of the pane contents.  The default is on.

When this question was asked, tmux didn't have an appropriate setting, but I prepared [a patch based on `tmux` 1.6](https://gist.github.com/1861273).

Comment: Brilliant! It worked perfectly, I appreciate the extra effort in making a patch! Although I suspected the answer would "it can't be done", this is probably the best way to say it :).

Comment: Also, you should consider making this depend on a configuration parameter and send it upstream.

Comment: In the end I ended up adding the option myself, it will be in 1.7

Comment: @JacobodeVera: Good for you.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe worth pointing out that this is now (definitely as of tmux 1.9a since that's what I'm on) available via the `wrap-search` setting:

```
$ man tmux | grep -B1 -A1 'will wrap'
         wrap-search [on | off]
                 If this option is set, searches will wrap around the end
                 of the pane contents.  The default is on.
```

Comment: haha, yeah, I ended up adding that feature and got the patch accepted :)